# How to make a tab programmatically clicked?

Tags: jquery

There are three tabs in a web page, and from another web page which I submit with action then I want to go to the page containing the tabs, and I want the third tab to be programmatically clicked ( selected ). How to achieve that?

Comment: What sort of tab? Whats your framework asp.net/ php/rails? Do you want this all to happen client side?

Answer (score 4):

Judging from your tags, I guess you are using jQuery-UI's tabs. In that case, just set the 'selected' option to 2.

```
$(selector).tabs({
   selected: 2
});
```

Documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-selected

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery,

```
$('#tabId').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reload the tab programmatically then i recommend use Jquery Tab API utility like below. It is quite simple and more importantly it also raises the events that would  normally be raised when you click on tab directly.

//This makes first tab active and then activates second tab

```
  $( "#myTabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 0 );
```

Also you can catch tabs active event like below for performing any operations

```
   $( "#myTabs" ).on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) {

    // your custom code on tab click

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.hash`. For example, on a page `index#tab` it will be `#tab`. Then select the tab as, as @Mike (if you are using jQuery) or @alexanderb answered.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what all of you wrote but it seems the code did not work. So I give here a bit of my page code , and perhaps someone can give the right solution :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(  function()
                        {

                            // Lorsqu'un lien a.tab est cliqué
                            $("a.tab").click(   function () 
                                                {
                                                    // Mettre tous les onglets non actifs
                                                    $(".active").removeClass("active");
                                                    // Mettre l'onglet cliqué actif
                                                    $(this).addClass("active");

                                                    // Cacher les boîtes de contenu
                                                    $(".content").slideUp();
                                                    // Pour afficher la boîte de contenu associé, nous
                                                    // avons modifié le titre du lien par le nom de
                                                    // l'identifiant de la boite de contenu
                                                    var contenu_aff = $(this).attr("title");
                                                    $("#" + contenu_aff).slideDown();
                                                }
                                              );
                        }
                    );


</script>

<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" title="Informationg&eacute;n&eacute;rale" class="tab active">Information g&eacute;n&eacute;rale</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Informationfinanci&egrave;re" class="tab">Information financi&egrave;re</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Cr&eacute;dits" class="tab">Cr&eacute;dits</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="Informationg&eacute;n&eacute;rale" class="content">
<center>
<form action="suivi.php?action=AdminModificationFicheClient" method="post" name="frm_Fiche" id="frm_Fiche">
```

etc...

So how to make the third tab be programmatically clicked from one another page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery and it will Click exacly the third Tab.

```
 $('.TabClassName').get(2).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is all client side code then you could do it in javascript using a query string

```
window.location = "http://www.somepage.com/?activetab=3"
```

then on the page with the tab on

```
$document.read(function(){
 var activeTab = getParameterByName(activeTab);

$("#youtabs").tabs({
   selected: activeTab 
});
})

function getParameterByName(name) {     
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)')
                    .exec(window.location.search);

    return match ?
        decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '))
        : null;     
}
```

This assumes you are using the jquery UI tab control.

Comment: I think you've overcomplicated it.

Comment: @Daniel Hanly You could explain how? Plus the question is very open and vague so any answer has to be fairly specific to counter this.

Comment: lines 4-6 of your answer, answers his question, the rest is garbage, no mention of URL passing in variables, yet you've built a regexp to disseminate this into a variable to use. Good function, but totally not needed. I agree with you, the question is vague, but like I said, lines 4-6 of your code answers his question, the rest is unneeded.